# EF Core Change Tracking - Reapply changes to freshly fetched entities in new DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, change-tracking

I want to achieve following scenario:

1. Multiple user might load an entity, **make changes concurrently**  and save them - **last wins**.
2. Only changed fields should be updated in database - other fields should not be overwritten if changed meanwhile.
3. Before saving, I need to load fresh data from database and **validate the fresh data with the changes** made by user.

My understanding is that I need to store change tracking information (Original Values) somewhere between load and save.

Since DbContext which contains the change tracking information is supposed to be short lived, I need to transfer the change tracking information between two DbContext instances.

How can I achieve something like this:

````cs
OrderEntity order;
EntityEntry<OrderEntity> entry; //change tracking information - original values
using (var dbContext1 = new MyDbContext())
{
   order = dbContext1.Orders.Single(x => x.Id == OrderId);      
   entry = dbContext1.Entry(order), 
}

//some time later, user edits some fields
order.Status = ....

//meanwhile, the data in database changes, e.g another user edits another field of the same 

```csharp
using (var dbContext2 = new MyDbContext())
{
   var freshOrder = dbContext.Orders.Single(x => x.Id == OrderId);
   ApplyChanges(freshOrder, entry); //How to do this!
   if (Validate(freshOrder))
   {
      dbContext.SaveChanges();
   }
}
````

Comment: Try the following `context.Entry(freshOrder).CurrentValues.SetValues(entry.Entity)`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: It will overwrite all fields in `freshOrder`, even those that has not changed in `entry.Entity`, doesn't it? So effectively all changes made by other user will be discarded and I don't want that